# Get list of devices on windows ad hoc network

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, ad-hoc-network

I was wondering if there was a command to get a list of all the devices connected to an ad-hoc network that I host from my laptop.

This far I've just been looking up the device ip with ipconfig or similar from the device itself, but I want to connect a device which I can only access through SSH for a presentation I'm making.

Is there a command or utility for seeing what devices are connected to my ad-hoc netowork?

(I'm on Windows 8)

Answer (score 2):

After some more searching I found that I could use `arp -a` to list all the known devices through different network connections that I had.

Here's how it worked:

- Start the hostednetwork on Windows through `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`
- Find out what your IP address is through `ipconfig` or through the network and sharing center
- Type `arp -a` to get a list of all your connections and known devices
- Find the interface with the IP you found earlier
- Now you'll have a list of known devices on that interface, which should be good enough.

Answer (score -1):

Try viewing the Network Map. Open the Control Panel (not PC settings) and go to Network and Sharing Center. Then you should find in the upper right corner a link to "See full map". This will work if your other devices are "discoverable" by Windows, which some may not be.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that I would have some way to see them via netsh or something, but I guess I'm going to have to make a program to have them phone home when they connect since they don't seem to be discoverable.